# Special Character must be escaped error in Dreamweaver HTML. Page won't load

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following line in my code but it gives me the error 
Special character must be escaped:[<]

```
<li class="illustration isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><img src="img/17.jpg"alt="Brain">
```

What is wrong?I'm still new to coding html and I took part of the code off another site that has worked for most of my site until here.

Comment: please give a full code or jsfiddle. so that easy to understand exact problem.

Comment: I found out what was wrong. Turns out the code I was trying to learn from uses Javascript and I didn't know. Should I delete my question? Thank you.